# Primary Key as domain username AND userID?

Tags: sql, primary-key-design, sql-types

I have read here that it is probably better to use an AI integer to denote users as opposed to an assigned domain (string) username.  I can accept that, however, when I am including in the 'users' table the auto generated userid and the unique domain usernames, how should I denote that in other tables as FKs?  eg.  Department table with 'userid' AND 'domainname' or just userid; hardware table with 'userid' AND 'domainname' or just 'userid' as owner?

Comment: it's not clear exactly what you're asking... can you give us more info about your table structure and what you're trying to achieve with it?

Comment: Its to track users, their hardware, network port/IP/MAC address, location, software. etc.  I want to use their domain userids as their unique identifier as they can't be a user without one.  Is it more proper to use an auto generated ID number for rows in tables?  Is it over-kill to use this AND their unique domain user account id (varchar not INT)?  I'd prefer to use the domain user account id eg. sdr35.  As an analogy, when a DB with a user table can use a social security number as a unique primary identfier/key, is it convention to instead use an auto INT id to be the PK instead? ...tnx

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you some Idea but not exact answer. *-"this answer is base on my understanding in your question"*

Design example :

Table `Users`:

*Your primary key here is `UserId` and you can use this as foreign key in other table.*

```
UserId | Usernames
```

Table `Department`:

*Your primary key here is `DepartmentId` and you can use this as foreign key in other table.*

*You also have a foreign key called `UserId` from table `Users`*

```
DepartmentId | UserId |DomainName
```

Table `Hardware`:

*Your primary key here is `HardwareId`*

*You also have 2 foreign keys called `DepartmentId` and `UserId`*

```
HardwareId | DepartmentId | UserId (optional) | Etc...
```

OK, Each table must and required to have a own primary key and you can't use the `DepartmentId` and `UserId` to become primary key in table `Hardware` because they are foreign key in this table.

`DepartmentId` - Include, so you will know the department where the hardware base.

`UserId` - (Optional), You will know the owner or user of this hardware by using only the `UserId`

Comment: Its to track users, their hardware, network port/IP/MAC address, location, software. etc.  I want to use their domain userids as their unique identifier as they can't be a user without one.  Is it more proper to use an auto generated ID number for rows in tables?  Is it over-kill to use this AND their unique domain user account id (varchar not INT)?  I'd prefer to use the domain user account id eg. sdr35.  As an analogy, when a DB with a user table can use a social security number as a unique primary identfier/key, is it convention to instead use an auto INT id to be the PK instead? ...tnx

Comment: Of course you can use the `unique domain id` and `SSS` as pk but be sure those value will not be repeated in primary key. see [varchar PK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19299874/can-i-use-varchar-as-the-primary-key) and [best practice PK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337503/whats-the-best-practice-for-primary-keys-in-tables)

Answer (score 0):

Just the user-ID. This is a key component of [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization); if the other tables contain any other information that can be completely determined by the user, then you introduce the risk of inconsistencies whereby different records make different claims about a given user.