# Mysql how to add foreign key issue with different collation

Tags: mysql

PARENT TABLE : app

- Parent table app having two columns ID,APP-ID.

**`id` int(11) not null auto_increment,**
**`App-id varchar(20) NOT NULL latin1_bin,**

Table column description: 
- ID = auto increment
- APP-ID = varchar with collation type latin1_bin

CHILD TBALE : app_ser

- Child table app_ser having two columns ID,APP-NAME

**`id` int(11) not null auto_increment,**
*`App-name varchar(20) NOT NULL latin1_swedish_ci,**

Table column description:
- ID = auto increment
- App_Name = varchar with collation type latin1_swedish_ci

My_goal_is:

1) Now i want add a "primary key" on parent table column App-id.

```
query cmd is : alter table app ADD PRIMARY KEY (App-id)
```

2) Next i am going to add "foreign key" on child table column App-name.

```
query cmd is : alter table app_ser ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_app_ser` FOREIGN KEY (`APP_NAME`) REFERENCES `app` (`APP_ID`)
```

Now I have issue on while run the foreign key query with error code 1215.
could you please help me on this ?

Thanks,
viswa

Comment: 1. The collations must be the same. Period. 2. Why do you reference the varchar field and not the id, which is integer?

Comment: Hi Shadow Thanks for your reply i will change my collation type as required. second thing is reference the varchar field and not integer.

Comment: It's because your 1st command is not running successfully.

Comment: It is not recommended to use primary key with varchar type. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19299874/can-i-use-varchar-as-the-primary-key