# Joining mulitple tables on a varchar key - MYSQL : Performance Issues

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join

MY Problem is that the join queries take around 7-15 seconds for 1,5 million datasets and i want to reduce it significantly but don't really know how.

I have a Database Designed as Followed:

Tbl1:  ID - Time1 - Time 2 - Time2

Tbl2:  ID - Topic_ID

Tbl3:  ID - Location_ID

Tbl4:  ID - Status_ID

The first ID is always the same and there are allways keys on both Columns. It is easily possible to join 2 tables but as soon as i try to join a 3rd on like for example:

```
Select t1.Time1,t2.Topic_ID,t3_Location_id 
from
(select ID,Time1 from tbl1 where time > 400 and < 500 ) as t1
inner join tbl2 as t2 on t2.Id = t1.ID
inner join tbl3 as t3 on t2.id = t3.ID
where t2.topic_ID = 2
```

The Time Grows massively from 0.02 secs to 7-15 secs.

MY Problem now is that there is a 1:1 Relation for all tables execpt for table 2 where it is possible that one Id has more than one Topic.

I Hope I explained my Problem decently.

Thank you very much for you Help

Comment: And all ID columns are indexed? What about t2.topic?

Comment: Yes Indexes everywhere possible

Comment: If it was Oracle I'd be recommending checking that the statistics for the tables are up to date. Can you do the equivalent for mysql? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/innodb/1.1/en/innodb-other-changes-statistics-estimation.html What are the data volumes like?

Comment: the time table is about 250 mb the rest  is about 80 mb each

Comment: I should add that my ID is a variableChar of 16 characters

Comment: can you please add the output for an explain on your query?

Comment: I haven't got real life data concerning speed but I believe `int` as primary key would be faster and altogether better choice. See for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7497421/using-varchar-as-the-primary-key-bad-idea-or-ok, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19299874/can-i-use-varchar-as-the-primary-key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try the below query and check once. I just added a group by clause in your derived table. What I feel is that group by will give u the unique combination of ID and TIME and thus will reduce the record set generated in ur derived table, in turn reducing performance.

```
            Select t1.Time1,t2.Topic_ID,t3_Location_id 
        from
        (select ID,Time1 from tbl1 where time > 400 and < 500 group by        ID,Time1) as t1
        inner join tbl2 as t2 on t2.Id = t1.ID
        inner join tbl3 as t3 on t2.id = t3.ID
        where t2.topic_ID = 2
```