# An error occurred while the batch was being executed. - SQL Server table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, primary-key, create-table

I've tried to add a table `utilizatori` to a SQL Server database. But, for some reason, it doesn't work. What could be the issue?

It seems like the email can't be a primary key, but for the project it must be. It explicitly says that email row must be primary key of `varchar` type. I'll attach the query result

```
Rename refactoring operation with key  is skipped, element [dbo].[Table].[Id] (SqlSimpleColumn) will not be renamed to email
Creating Table [dbo].[utilizatori]...
```

> (62,1): SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider:
> Msg 1919, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> Column 'email' in table 'utilizatori' is of a type that is invalid for use as a key column in an index.

```
(62,0): SQL72045: Script execution error.  The executed script:
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[utilizatori] 
(
    [email]   VARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [parola]  VARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [nume]    VARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [prenume] VARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([email] ASC)
);
```

> (62,1): SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider:
> Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
> Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

Comment: Don't make an email address a primary key, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7497421/using-varchar-as-the-primary-key-bad-idea-or-ok). Instead assign an int to serve as an ID. Email addresses may change. You can always place a unique constraint on that column if it's not valid for multiple records to have the same email address.

Comment: You can't use varchar(max) as the error indicates. Why are you using `max` anyway? How big do you think an email address can be? (You can Google that)

Comment: The thing is, it's a task for a contest practice. And in the database part, it explicitly says that the e-mail must be the primary key. I know it's weird, usually the primary key is an int, but that's the requirement...

Comment: @Stu well, not very big. But I've heard that you should put max to be sure it's enough every time you have a field where entries are strings

Comment: Any index in SQL Server can be **at most** 900 bytes (give or take) big - a `varchar(max)` could be up to 2 GB in size. You simply **CANNOT** index a `varchar(max)` column - so don't just use `varchar(max)` out of lazyness and ignorance - use a **appropriate length**  for all your varchar columns !

Comment: `I've heard that you should put max to be sure it's enough every time you have a field where entries are strings` -> nope. You've heard bad advice. See [this, for example](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/162113/), and [this](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type).

Comment: Okay, very good to know. Thanks for the advices!

Comment: Doesn't seem like a contest worth participating in if they are specifically asking for a bad design. A unique constraint I could understand, but not a PK.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the datatype. `Varchar(max)` can not be used for creating Primary Keys.
Try changing `Varchar(max)` by for example `Varchar(255)`.

Comment: Technically an e-mail should be `nvarchar` and at least 320 characters (64 for username + `@` + 255 for domain), but since users can add characters like `+` signs to their username to help identify e-mail harvesters, and the e-mail is still valid, should probably be a lot bigger (just not MAX obviously). If I were designing a new system today I would probably use `nvarchar(450)`.